# Application get sigkill on launch

Tags: macos, high-sierra, security, code-signing, gatekeeper

When I launch certain applications, they don't launch. Running them in iTerm gets `sigkill`. Running them in `gdb` does not output any debug information. Running them with `dtruss` does not output any debug information. However, running them in a virtual machine (with SIP and amfi disabled) succeed, so it must be that something is wrong with my system's configuration. How can I start to troubleshoot this problem?

Note: I saw relevant messages of `amfid` in `Console.app` and killed `amfid`, and then applications begin to freeze. (Problems I should expect for killing a system process. But what actually is `amfid` doing if I had already disabled it using the startup flag `amfi_get_out_of_my_way=0x1`? And it probably worked because I can create APFS snapshots using my own program I signed ad-hoc, which will just get a `sigkill` if `amfi` is enabled.)

Console.app messages:

```
调试  22:19:00.631755 +0800   amfid   mig_source_handler: enter
信息  22:19:00.631993 +0800   amfid   Verifying fallback entitlements on /Applications/Paste.app/Contents/MacOS/Paste
调试  22:19:00.633074 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e45f00bb0 rule ^Contents$ added (weight 0, flags 0x12)
调试  22:19:00.633180 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e45f00860 rule ^(\.LSOverride|\.DS_Store|Icon
|\.SoftwareDepot\.tracking)$ added (weight 0, flags 0x9)
调试  22:19:00.633231 +0800   amfid   entering /Applications/Paste.app
调试  22:19:00.633329 +0800   amfid   entering /Applications/Paste.app/Contents
调试  22:19:00.633394 +0800   amfid   leaving /Applications/Paste.app/Contents
调试  22:19:00.633425 +0800   amfid   leaving /Applications/Paste.app
调试  22:19:00.633730 +0800   amfid   open(/Applications/Paste.app/Contents/MacOS/Paste,0x0,0x1b6) = 3
调试  22:19:00.633788 +0800   amfid   open(/Applications/Paste.app/Contents/MacOS/Paste,0x0,0x1b6) = 4
调试  22:19:00.633826 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e45e4f9e0 is a thin file (x86_64)
调试  22:19:00.633860 +0800   amfid   close(3) err: 0
调试  22:19:00.633977 +0800   amfid   17387 signing bytes in 4 blob(s) from /Applications/Paste.app/Contents/MacOS/Paste(x86_64)
调试  22:19:00.634042 +0800   amfid   failed to fetch /Applications/Paste.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeRequirements-1 error=-10
调试  22:19:00.634265 +0800   amfid   create 0x7f8e45e46597 for 0x7f8e45e46580
调试  22:19:00.634327 +0800   amfid   create 0x7f8e45e592b8 for 0x7f8e45e592a0
调试  22:19:00.634444 +0800   amfid   Policy() this 0x7f8e45e32008
调试  22:19:00.634505 +0800   amfid   ~Policy() this 0x7f8e45e32008
调试  22:19:00.634579 +0800   amfid   create 0x7f8e45e403b9 for 0x7f8e45e403a0
调试  22:19:00.634614 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e45e403a0 attached module 0x7f8e45c00860(AppleX509CL) (ssid 0 type 8)
调试  22:19:00.634827 +0800   amfid   create 0x7f8e45c03cda for 0x7f8e45c03cc0
调试  22:19:00.634909 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e45c03cc0 attached module 0x7f8e45e42d10(AppleCSP) (ssid 0 type 2)
调试  22:19:00.634956 +0800   amfid   create 0x7f8e45f2b76b for 0x7f8e45f2b770
调试  22:19:00.635055 +0800   amfid   Empty start date
调试  22:19:00.635087 +0800   amfid   Empty end date
调试  22:19:00.635739 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e45c03cc0 detach module 0x7f8e45e42d10(AppleCSP)
调试  22:19:00.636227 +0800   trustd  XPC [amfid[578]/1#3 LF=0] operation: trust_evaluate (8)
调试  22:19:00.637160 +0800   amfid   SecTrustSettingsEvaluateCert: NOT FOUND
调试  22:19:00.637273 +0800   amfid   open(/Applications/Paste.app/Contents/Info.plist,0x0,0x1b6) = 3
调试  22:19:00.637440 +0800   amfid   close(3) err: 0
调试  22:19:00.637497 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e4682f630 validating slot -1
调试  22:19:00.637545 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e4682f630 validating slot -1
调试  22:19:00.637668 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e45c01c78 loaded InfoDict 0x7f8e45c00f20
调试  22:19:00.637701 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e4682f630 validating slot -5
调试  22:19:00.637740 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e4682f630 validating slot -5
调试  22:19:00.637796 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e45c01c78 loaded Entitlements 0x7f8e45c03d90
调试  22:19:00.637889 +0800   amfid   failed to fetch /Applications/Paste.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeTopDirectory error=-10
调试  22:19:00.637922 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e4682f630 validating slot -2
调试  22:19:00.637967 +0800   amfid   open(/Applications/Paste.app/Contents/MacOS/Paste,0x0,0x1b6) = 3
调试  22:19:00.638000 +0800   amfid   3 fcntl(48,0x1) = 0
调试  22:19:00.668608 +0800   amfid   close(3) err: 0
默认  22:19:00.668669 +0800   amfid   MacOS error: -67050
调试  22:19:00.669774 +0800   amfid   0   Security                            0x00007fff3f48bb23 Security::CommonError::LogBacktrace() + 87
调试  22:19:00.669822 +0800   amfid   1   Security                            0x00007fff3f48c043 Security::MacOSError::MacOSError(int) + 241
调试  22:19:00.669960 +0800   amfid   2   Security                            0x00007fff3f48c0de Security::MacOSError::throwMe(int) + 34
调试  22:19:00.670006 +0800   amfid   3   Security                            0x00007fff3f37662e Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidateCore(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 94
调试  22:19:00.670049 +0800   amfid   4   Security                            0x00007fff3f37444d Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidate(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 71
调试  22:19:00.670081 +0800   amfid   5   Security                            0x00007fff3f36c962 SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors + 163
调试  22:19:00.670112 +0800   amfid   6   amfid                               0x000000010d09d488 amfid + 9352
调试  22:19:00.670144 +0800   amfid   7   amfid                               0x000000010d09c802 amfid + 6146
调试  22:19:00.670173 +0800   amfid   8   amfid                               0x000000010d09f136 amfid + 16694
调试  22:19:00.670206 +0800   amfid   9   amfid                               0x000000010d09f1ac amfid + 16812
调试  22:19:00.670237 +0800   amfid   10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3c5fca dispatch_mig_server + 413
调试  22:19:00.670267 +0800   amfid   11  amfid                               0x000000010d09cd73 amfid + 7539
调试  22:19:00.670295 +0800   amfid   12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3b9db8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
调试  22:19:00.670325 +0800   amfid   13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3cce81 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472
调试  22:19:00.670373 +0800   amfid   14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3bc081 _dispatch_source_invoke + 620
调试  22:19:00.670438 +0800   amfid   15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3ce07a _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 222
调试  22:19:00.670500 +0800   amfid   16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3c1166 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 373
调试  22:19:00.670554 +0800   amfid   17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3cf1c9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_item + 256
调试  22:19:00.670622 +0800   amfid   18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3d28f3 _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 817
调试  22:19:00.670687 +0800   amfid   19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5b70aff6 _pthread_wqthread + 1016
调试  22:19:00.670757 +0800   amfid   20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5b70abe9 start_wqthread + 13
默认  22:19:00.670909 +0800   amfid   MacOS error: -67050
调试  22:19:00.672012 +0800   amfid   0   Security                            0x00007fff3f48bb23 Security::CommonError::LogBacktrace() + 87
调试  22:19:00.672052 +0800   amfid   1   Security                            0x00007fff3f48c043 Security::MacOSError::MacOSError(int) + 241
调试  22:19:00.672089 +0800   amfid   2   Security                            0x00007fff3f3765b6 Security::CodeSigning::CSError::CSError(int, __CFDictionary const*) + 18
调试  22:19:00.672125 +0800   amfid   3   Security                            0x00007fff3f380277 Security::CodeSigning::CSError::throwMe(int, __CFString const*, void const*) + 67
调试  22:19:00.672167 +0800   amfid   4   Security                            0x00007fff3f376756 Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidateCore(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 390
调试  22:19:00.672203 +0800   amfid   5   Security                            0x00007fff3f37444d Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidate(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 71
调试  22:19:00.672234 +0800   amfid   6   Security                            0x00007fff3f36c962 SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors + 163
调试  22:19:00.672266 +0800   amfid   7   amfid                               0x000000010d09d488 amfid + 9352
调试  22:19:00.672328 +0800   amfid   8   amfid                               0x000000010d09c802 amfid + 6146
调试  22:19:00.672380 +0800   amfid   9   amfid                               0x000000010d09f136 amfid + 16694
调试  22:19:00.672411 +0800   amfid   10  amfid                               0x000000010d09f1ac amfid + 16812
调试  22:19:00.672466 +0800   amfid   11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3c5fca dispatch_mig_server + 413
调试  22:19:00.672497 +0800   amfid   12  amfid                               0x000000010d09cd73 amfid + 7539
调试  22:19:00.672549 +0800   amfid   13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3b9db8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
调试  22:19:00.672599 +0800   amfid   14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3cce81 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472
调试  22:19:00.672635 +0800   amfid   15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3bc081 _dispatch_source_invoke + 620
调试  22:19:00.672685 +0800   amfid   16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3ce07a _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 222
调试  22:19:00.672716 +0800   amfid   17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3c1166 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 373
调试  22:19:00.672767 +0800   amfid   18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3cf1c9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_item + 256
调试  22:19:00.672819 +0800   amfid   19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3d28f3 _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 817
调试  22:19:00.672916 +0800   amfid   20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5b70aff6 _pthread_wqthread + 1016
调试  22:19:00.672991 +0800   amfid   21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5b70abe9 start_wqthread + 13
调试  22:19:00.673257 +0800   amfid   Bundle: CFBundle 0x7f8e45e0be50 </System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework> (framework, loaded), key: -2147411889, value: -2147411889, table: SecErrorMessages, localizationName: (null), result: -2147411889
调试  22:19:00.673310 +0800   amfid   Bundle: CFBundle 0x7f8e45e0be50 </System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework> (framework, loaded), key: -2147411889, value: -2147411889, table: SecDebugErrorMessages, localizationName: (null), result: CSSMERR_CL_UNKNOWN_TAG
调试  22:19:00.673429 +0800   amfid   Bundle: CFBundle 0x7f8e45e0be50 </System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework> (framework, loaded), key: -2147411889, value: -2147411889, table: SecErrorMessages, localizationName: (null), result: -2147411889
调试  22:19:00.673473 +0800   amfid   Bundle: CFBundle 0x7f8e45e0be50 </System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework> (framework, loaded), key: -2147411889, value: -2147411889, table: SecDebugErrorMessages, localizationName: (null), result: CSSMERR_CL_UNKNOWN_TAG
默认  22:19:00.673562 +0800   amfid   MacOS error: -67050
调试  22:19:00.674409 +0800   amfid   0   Security                            0x00007fff3f48bb23 Security::CommonError::LogBacktrace() + 87
调试  22:19:00.674454 +0800   amfid   1   Security                            0x00007fff3f48c043 Security::MacOSError::MacOSError(int) + 241
调试  22:19:00.674509 +0800   amfid   2   Security                            0x00007fff3f48c0de Security::MacOSError::throwMe(int) + 34
调试  22:19:00.674548 +0800   amfid   3   Security                            0x00007fff3f37662e Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidateCore(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 94
调试  22:19:00.674590 +0800   amfid   4   Security                            0x00007fff3f37444d Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidate(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 71
调试  22:19:00.674622 +0800   amfid   5   Security                            0x00007fff3f36c962 SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors + 163
调试  22:19:00.674652 +0800   amfid   6   amfid                               0x000000010d09d4c3 amfid + 9411
调试  22:19:00.674680 +0800   amfid   7   amfid                               0x000000010d09c802 amfid + 6146
调试  22:19:00.674710 +0800   amfid   8   amfid                               0x000000010d09f136 amfid + 16694
调试  22:19:00.674744 +0800   amfid   9   amfid                               0x000000010d09f1ac amfid + 16812
调试  22:19:00.674774 +0800   amfid   10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3c5fca dispatch_mig_server + 413
调试  22:19:00.674803 +0800   amfid   11  amfid                               0x000000010d09cd73 amfid + 7539
调试  22:19:00.674832 +0800   amfid   12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3b9db8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
调试  22:19:00.674872 +0800   amfid   13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3cce81 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472
调试  22:19:00.674943 +0800   amfid   14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3bc081 _dispatch_source_invoke + 620
调试  22:19:00.675000 +0800   amfid   15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3ce07a _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 222
调试  22:19:00.675072 +0800   amfid   16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3c1166 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 373
调试  22:19:00.675132 +0800   amfid   17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3cf1c9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_item + 256
调试  22:19:00.675190 +0800   amfid   18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3d28f3 _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 817
调试  22:19:00.675242 +0800   amfid   19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5b70aff6 _pthread_wqthread + 1016
调试  22:19:00.675299 +0800   amfid   20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5b70abe9 start_wqthread + 13
默认  22:19:00.675418 +0800   amfid   MacOS error: -67050
调试  22:19:00.676450 +0800   amfid   0   Security                            0x00007fff3f48bb23 Security::CommonError::LogBacktrace() + 87
调试  22:19:00.676489 +0800   amfid   1   Security                            0x00007fff3f48c043 Security::MacOSError::MacOSError(int) + 241
调试  22:19:00.676514 +0800   amfid   2   Security                            0x00007fff3f3765b6 Security::CodeSigning::CSError::CSError(int, __CFDictionary const*) + 18
调试  22:19:00.676546 +0800   amfid   3   Security                            0x00007fff3f380277 Security::CodeSigning::CSError::throwMe(int, __CFString const*, void const*) + 67
调试  22:19:00.676583 +0800   amfid   4   Security                            0x00007fff3f376756 Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidateCore(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 390
调试  22:19:00.676625 +0800   amfid   5   Security                            0x00007fff3f37444d Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidate(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 71
调试  22:19:00.676656 +0800   amfid   6   Security                            0x00007fff3f36c962 SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors + 163
调试  22:19:00.676695 +0800   amfid   7   amfid                               0x000000010d09d4c3 amfid + 9411
调试  22:19:00.676764 +0800   amfid   8   amfid                               0x000000010d09c802 amfid + 6146
调试  22:19:00.676795 +0800   amfid   9   amfid                               0x000000010d09f136 amfid + 16694
调试  22:19:00.676825 +0800   amfid   10  amfid                               0x000000010d09f1ac amfid + 16812
调试  22:19:00.676855 +0800   amfid   11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3c5fca dispatch_mig_server + 413
调试  22:19:00.676889 +0800   amfid   12  amfid                               0x000000010d09cd73 amfid + 7539
调试  22:19:00.676949 +0800   amfid   13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3b9db8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
调试  22:19:00.677012 +0800   amfid   14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3cce81 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472
调试  22:19:00.677069 +0800   amfid   15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3bc081 _dispatch_source_invoke + 620
调试  22:19:00.677170 +0800   amfid   16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3ce07a _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 222
调试  22:19:00.677198 +0800   amfid   17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3c1166 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 373
调试  22:19:00.677335 +0800   amfid   18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3cf1c9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_item + 256
调试  22:19:00.677375 +0800   amfid   19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3d28f3 _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 817
调试  22:19:00.677406 +0800   amfid   20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5b70aff6 _pthread_wqthread + 1016
调试  22:19:00.677438 +0800   amfid   21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5b70abe9 start_wqthread + 13
调试  22:19:00.677776 +0800   amfid   0x7f8e45e403a0 detach module 0x7f8e45c00860(AppleX509CL)
调试  22:19:00.677938 +0800   amfid   close(4) err: 0
调试  22:19:00.677997 +0800   amfid   mig_source_handler: exit
```

`gdb`

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Applications/Paste.app/Contents/MacOS/Paste
[New Thread 0x1103 of process 1535]
[New Thread 0xe03 of process 1535]

Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
The program no longer exists.
```

`lldb`

```
(lldb) target create "/Applications/Paste.app/Contents/MacOS/Paste"
Current executable set to '/Applications/Paste.app/Contents/MacOS/Paste' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
error: process exited with status -1 (unable to attach)
```

`dtruss`

```
dtrace: failed to execute /Applications/Paste.app/Contents/MacOS/Paste: Could not create symbolicator for task
```

Running `spctl --assess /Applications/Paste.app` hangs, with repeated messages in Console:

```
调试  19:00:42.831648 +0800   syspolicyd  0   Security                            0x00007fff3f48bb23 Security::CommonError::LogBacktrace() + 87
调试  19:00:42.831755 +0800   syspolicyd  1   Security                            0x00007fff3f48c043 Security::MacOSError::MacOSError(int) + 241
调试  19:00:42.831912 +0800   syspolicyd  2   Security                            0x00007fff3f3765b6 Security::CodeSigning::CSError::CSError(int, __CFDictionary const*) + 18
调试  19:00:42.831966 +0800   syspolicyd  3   Security                            0x00007fff3f380277 Security::CodeSigning::CSError::throwMe(int, __CFString const*, void const*) + 67
调试  19:00:42.867965 +0800   syspolicyd  4   Security                            0x00007fff3f376756 Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidateCore(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 390
调试  19:00:42.868193 +0800   syspolicyd  5   Security                            0x00007fff3f37444d Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidate(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 71
调试  19:00:42.869378 +0800   syspolicyd  6   Security                            0x00007fff3f36c962 SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors + 163
调试  19:00:42.869444 +0800   syspolicyd  7   Security                            0x00007fff3f38e1d6 Security::CodeSigning::PolicyEngine::evaluateCodeItem(__SecCode const*, __CFURL const*, unsigned int, unsigned long long, bool, __CFDictionary*) + 644
调试  19:00:42.870000 +0800   syspolicyd  8   Security                            0x00007fff3f390211 invocation function for block in Security::CodeSigning::PolicyEngine::evaluateCode(__CFURL const*, unsigned int, unsigned long long, __CFDictionary const*, __CFDictionary*, bool) + 319
调试  19:00:42.870180 +0800   syspolicyd  9   Security                            0x00007fff3f37454d Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidate(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 327
调试  19:00:42.870291 +0800   syspolicyd  10  Security                            0x00007fff3f37396b Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::validateNestedCode(__CFURL const*, Security::CodeSigning::ResourceSeal const&, unsigned int, bool) + 213
调试  19:00:42.870464 +0800   syspolicyd  11  Security                            0x00007fff3f372885 Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::validateResource(__CFDictionary const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::ValidationContext&, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 1423
调试  19:00:42.870641 +0800   syspolicyd  12  Security                            0x00007fff3f3722b2 invocation function for block in Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::validateResources(unsigned int) + 77
调试  19:00:42.870696 +0800   syspolicyd  13  Security                            0x00007fff3f381e42 Security::CodeSigning::LimitedAsync::perform(Security::Dispatch::Group&, void () block_pointer) + 204
调试  19:00:42.870740 +0800   syspolicyd  14  Security                            0x00007fff3f3721b1 invocation function for block in Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::validateResources(unsigned int) + 235
调试  19:00:42.870795 +0800   syspolicyd  15  Security                            0x00007fff3f3999d8 Security::CodeSigning::ResourceBuilder::scan(void (_ftsent*, unsigned int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, Security::CodeSigning::ResourceBuilder::Rule*) block_pointer) + 2968
调试  19:00:42.870862 +0800   syspolicyd  16  Security                            0x00007fff3f3718ab Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::validateResources(unsigned int) + 823
调试  19:00:42.870906 +0800   syspolicyd  17  Security                            0x00007fff3f3744e0 Security::CodeSigning::SecStaticCode::staticValidate(unsigned int, Security::CodeSigning::SecRequirement const*) + 218
调试  19:00:42.870965 +0800   syspolicyd  18  Security                            0x00007fff3f36c962 SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors + 163
调试  19:00:42.871034 +0800   syspolicyd  19  Security                            0x00007fff3f38fc32 Security::CodeSigning::PolicyEngine::evaluateCode(__CFURL const*, unsigned int, unsigned long long, __CFDictionary const*, __CFDictionary*, bool) + 802
调试  19:00:42.871078 +0800   syspolicyd  20  Security                            0x00007fff3f386381 ___ZN8Security11CodeSigning14EvaluationTask17performEvaluationEyPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke.9 + 216
调试  19:00:42.871654 +0800   syspolicyd  21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3cfe0e _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 102
调试  19:00:42.871838 +0800   syspolicyd  22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3b9db8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
调试  19:00:42.871968 +0800   syspolicyd  23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3ce217 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 635
调试  19:00:42.872080 +0800   syspolicyd  24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3c1166 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 373
调试  19:00:42.872205 +0800   syspolicyd  25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3cef0d _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 332
调试  19:00:42.872316 +0800   syspolicyd  26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5b3d2d21 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 880
调试  19:00:42.872435 +0800   syspolicyd  27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5b70afd2 _pthread_wqthread + 980
调试  19:00:42.872654 +0800   syspolicyd  28  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5b70abe9 start_wqthread + 13
默认  19:00:42.873339 +0800   syspolicyd  MacOS error: -67050
```

Comment: Sounds like these applications do not have a valid code signature. Where did you get the failing applications from?

Comment: @jksoegaard I forget. I will try to download it again from the official website.

Comment: Also, resigning it with ad-hoc seems to work (application launches), but give error message: `The application is missing required entitlement com.apple.developer.icloud-services`. I guess the entitlement is why it triggered `amfid`?

Answer (score 1):

The application have valid signature (`codesign --verify -vv --deep --strict`; `codesign -dvv` passed), but it trips `amfi` (killed) and `spctl` (hangs with 100% CPU) for whatever reason.

To run it without downloading a new version, sign it again with entitlements:

1. `codesign -d --entitlements :- > entitlements.plist`,
2. Add `com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation`,
3. Sign it ad-hoc: `codesign --force -s - --entitlements ent2.plist /Applications/Paste.app`.